# Multiple, connected images: labelling and page fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing

Thanks to this previously asked question [How to connect images with arrows in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487616/how-to-connect-images-with-arrows-in-latex/679098?noredirect=1#comment1685353_679098)

I was able to create a set of immages connected by arrows. However, I hav two questions :

- how do I label each of the images (to refer in the text to e.g. figure 1.2 or 1.5)
- for some reasons, the generated image fills all the page (visually it's more of an half page) or, at least, no text is allowed on the same page of the image. Any idea on how to correct this issue?

thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[lablum/.style={label=below:#1,name=img-#1},
marr/.style={line width=1mm,-latex}]
\matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=5mm] (mat)
{ \node[lablum=1]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-     duck}};
 & \node[lablum=2]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};\\
\node[lablum=4]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
& \node[lablum=3]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};\\
\node[lablum=5]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
& \node[lablum=6]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};\\
};
\draw[marr] (img-1) -- (img-2);
\draw[marr] ([xshift=1mm]img-2.south east) coordinate (aux) 
-- (img-3.north-|aux);
\draw[marr] (img-3) -- (img-4);
\draw[marr] ([xshift=-1mm]img-4.south west) coordinate (aux) 
-- (img-5.north-|aux);
\draw[marr] (img-5) -- (img-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you usually create "sub"figures (subcaptions)? There is more than one way/package that does this. There's a chance they can be used inside of a node (including the `\label`).

Comment: Ive tried \label in different positions, doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with a `matrix`, you can simplify things. First, I would use the option `matrix of nodes` (you need to load the `matrix` library for this), which makes it much easier to style the matrix nodes.

Then, you can set the labels automatically by using the current `figure` counter (and adding 1 to it, because it is only updated once the `\caption` is typeset) and append to it the argument you give via your `lablum` style.

Note that it is already possible to refer to matrix nodes using specific node names, for example the first node in the upper left corner of your matrix would be `mat-1-1`, so you don't need to define your own node names, but since you want to place the subfigures in a boustrophedonic manner, I kept it your way.

As for your problem that the figure fills the whole page: This is probably due to the size of the subfigures. Try to scale them a bit. The below example shows that the figure should be placed on a page with text if this is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    lablum/.style={
        label=below:{\pgfmathparse{int(\thefigure+1)}\pgfmathresult.#1},
        name={img-#1},
    },
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm] (mat)
{ |[lablum=1]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum=2]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  |[lablum=4]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum=3]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  |[lablum=5]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum=6]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
};
\draw[marr] (img-1) -- (img-2);
\draw[marr] ([xshift=1mm]img-2.south east) coordinate (aux) 
    -- (img-3.north-|aux);
\draw[marr] (img-3) -- (img-4);
\draw[marr] ([xshift=-1mm]img-4.south west) coordinate (aux) 
    -- (img-5.north-|aux);
\draw[marr] (img-5) -- (img-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can let Ti*k*Z/PGF also completely automatically calculate the labels for you (you only need to somehow tell the column count beforehand):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    boustrophedon matrix/.style args={#1/#2}{
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells, 
        boustrophedon matrix column count/.initial={#2},
        boustrophedon matrix step cell counter/.code={
            \pgfmathparse{
                mod(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 2) == 0 ?
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * 
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentrow -
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn + 1) :
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * 
                    (\pgfmatrixcurrentrow - 1) + 
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
            } 
            \global\pgfkeyslet{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        execute at begin cell={
            |[boustrophedon matrix step cell counter, label={below:{
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\thefigure+1)}\pgfmathresult.%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}
                }
            },
            name={#1-index-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}}]|
        },
    },
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[boustrophedon matrix={matrix one/2}, column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm]{ 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
};

\draw[marr] (matrix one-index-1) -- (matrix one-index-2);
\draw[marr] (matrix one-index-2.south east) -- (matrix one-index-3.north east);
\draw[marr] (matrix one-index-3) -- (matrix one-index-4);
\draw[marr] (matrix one-index-4.south west) -- (matrix one-index-5.north west);
\draw[marr] (matrix one-index-5) -- (matrix one-index-6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With three columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    boustrophedon matrix/.style args={#1/#2}{
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells, 
        boustrophedon matrix column count/.initial={#2},
        boustrophedon matrix step cell counter/.code={
            \pgfmathparse{
                mod(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 2) == 0 ?
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * (\pgfmatrixcurrentrow) -
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn + 1) :
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * (\pgfmatrixcurrentrow - 1) + 
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
            } 
            \global\pgfkeyslet{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        execute at begin cell={
            |[boustrophedon matrix step cell counter, label={below:{
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\thefigure+1)}\pgfmathresult.%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}
                }
            },
            name={#1-index-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}}]|
        },
    },
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[boustrophedon matrix={matrix two/3}, column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm]{ 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
};

\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-1) -- (matrix two-index-2);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-2) -- (matrix two-index-3);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-3.south east) -- (matrix two-index-4.north east);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-4) -- (matrix two-index-5);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-5) -- (matrix two-index-6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Referencing is probably easier using the `subcaption` package, but you can always create your own reference counters (I created a macro `\refsetcounter` that is based on `\refstepcounter` but instead of increasing the counter sets it to a specific value which comes in handy here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcounter{matrix}
\newcounter{matrixnode}[matrix]
\renewcommand*{\thematrixnode}{\thematrix.\arabic{matrixnode}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refsetcounter}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    boustrophedon matrix/.style args={#1/#2}{
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells, 
        boustrophedon matrix column count/.initial={#2},
        boustrophedon matrix step cell counter/.code={
            \pgfmathparse{
                mod(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 2) == 0 ?
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * (\pgfmatrixcurrentrow) -
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn + 1) :
                int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix column count} * (\pgfmatrixcurrentrow - 1) + 
                    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
            } 
            \global\pgfkeyslet{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        row 1 column 1/.append style={
            execute at begin cell={
                \refstepcounter{matrix}
            }
        },
        execute at begin cell={
            |[boustrophedon matrix step cell counter, label={below:{
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\thefigure+1)}\pgfmathresult.%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}
                    \refsetcounter{matrixnode}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}}
                    \label{matrixnode:#1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}}
                }
            },
            name={#1-index-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/boustrophedon matrix cell counter}}]|
        },
    },
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[boustrophedon matrix={matrix two/3}, column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm]{ 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
};

\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-1) -- (matrix two-index-2);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-2) -- (matrix two-index-3);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-3.south east) -- (matrix two-index-4.north east);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-4) -- (matrix two-index-5);
\draw[marr] (matrix two-index-5) -- (matrix two-index-6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}

See subfigure \ref{matrixnode:matrix two-1} and \ref{matrixnode:matrix two-4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I am not quite sure what you're after. If you want to keep the labelling and captioning customizable, maybe something like this could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcounter{matrix}
\newcounter{matrixnode}[matrix]
\renewcommand*{\thematrixnode}{\thematrix.\arabic{matrixnode}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refsetcounter}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    my custom matrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes in empty cells, 
        nodes={
            fill=red!10,
            minimum height=3.25cm,
            minimum width=3.25cm,
        },
        every label/.style={
            minimum height=0pt,
        },
        lablum/.style args={##1/##2}{
            label=below:{%
                \pgfmathparse{int(\thefigure+1)}\pgfmathresult.##1: ##2%
                \refsetcounter{matrixnode}{##1}\label{matrixnode:#1-##1}%
            },
            name={#1-index-##1},
        },
        my custom matrix initialise/.code={
            \refstepcounter{matrix}
        },
        my custom matrix initialise
    },
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm, my custom matrix={mat}] { 
  |[lablum={1/my caption}]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum={2/foo}]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
  |[lablum={7/bar}]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum={5/baz}]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} & 
  |[lablum={3/foo}]| \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck} \\
};
\draw[marr] (mat-index-1) -- (mat-index-2);
\draw[marr] (mat-index-3) -- (mat-index-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}

See subfigure \ref{matrixnode:mat-1} and \ref{matrixnode:mat-5}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added some styling to make the matrix cells have the same size. To make this more clear, I added some color to the nodes to show, which you can simply remove (by deleting `fill=red!10`).

---

Finally, things might be a lot easier using the `subcaption` package, however, you won't be easily able to freely position the nodes (for example from right to left):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    marr/.style={
        line width=1mm,
        -latex
    }]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=5mm] (mat) { 
  \subcaptionbox{foo\label{subfig:1-1}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}} & 
  \subcaptionbox{bar\label{subfig:1-2}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}} \\
  \subcaptionbox{baz\label{subfig:1-3}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}} & 
  \subcaptionbox{foo\label{subfig:1-4}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}} & 
  \subcaptionbox{bar\label{subfig:1-5}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}} \\
};
\draw[marr] (mat-1-1) -- (mat-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A matrix of figures.}
\label{fig:pffft}
\end{figure}

See subfigure \ref{subfig:1-1} and \ref{subfig:1-5}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. Nevertheless, what if I want to keep the first option (using lablum, i.e. custom numbering and use the \ref in the text? To be more precise, I need to have 2 images on the first row, 3 on the second and 2 again on the third row (like everything points to the last image on the right). so matrix should be
1.1 1.2 \\
1.3 1.4 1.7 \\
1.5 1.6 \\
and possibly with some text on each caption

Comment: @Achille I am not sure, what you're after ... maybe my last edit is something you can work with?

Comment: @Achille Maybe you just take a look at the `subcaption` package ... it is highly customisable and might actually better suit your needs.

Comment: your last solution works fine, thanks. However, if images have different sizes (which seems inevitable once I don't use ducks ;) ), the matrix is a bit messed up (rows are not equally spaced, arrows are no longer horizontal, etc). 
edit : everything is aligned on captions, it's probably better to align on the center of the images - no idea how

Comment: @Achille You should take a look at [the PDF/Ti*k*Z manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) in chapter 20 "Matrices and Alignment"

Comment: thanks. I've taken a look and I've seen row/column distances can be custom-adjusted. However, it's a bit trial&error. I think the best way is to replace each "duck-image" with a fixed size box (or a pre-defined surface) and fill this box/surface with the custom image - any hint on how to do that? Or - is there a more simple solution? in the very end my problem is to provide 7 images (of different sizes), linked with arrows, well aligned and in a "clean way (horizontal lines between column1&2, etc)

Comment: @Achille Cells in a matrix are just nodes which you can set the height and width using `minimum height` or `minimum width`. I think, this is indeed the simplest way, since you probably would like to have the labels aligned to each other as well. See the edit on the second to last example in my answer (the one with the now reddish background to the nodes).